# JavaScript REST API access doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, xmlhttprequest

Hi together, I am trying to get access to a REST API, but nothing works very well. I looked through the topics but no solution worked for me.

I must authorize with username and password, and my link works, when I open it manually in the browser. The browser shows me the json object, which i expect.

I always get status = "0" when i try to login with credentials and username+password in the xhttp.open method

If I try like in the example code I get the error: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" missing.

EDIT: When I manually try to open the page, the browser is popping up the login window with following message:

https://myRESTAPIURL.com requires a username and password. Website output: "< unspecified>"

```
var test = [];  
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

// function to be executed, when the readystate changes
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    alert(this.status);
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       // Typical action to be performed when the document is ready:
       test = xhttp.response;
    }
};

var url = "www.myURLWithRESTAPI.com";
xhttp.responseType = "json";
xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password"));
xhttp.send();
```